# update sqlite database for existing primary key

Tags: sqlite, coronasdk

I only need to update one sqlite database entry (this is inside Corona SDK but the commands are the same)

'place' is Table name and xcor is first column in my database. I have tried both of the following but none of them updates that particular entry.

```
UPDATE place SET xcor = testvalue[3] WHERE Id=databaseid;

[INSERT OR REPLACE INTO place VALUES (databaseid, ']]..testvalue[1]..[[',']]..testvalue[2]..[[',']]..testvalue[3]..[[');
```

The command insert works fine with parameters for entering a new entry however I need to update an existing entry.

Comment: Show the actual code that execute the SQL command(s).

Comment: "databaseid"  is the primary key, I noticed if I use a number the command works however, I need this to work with the variable

Comment: local tablefill2 =[[DELETE FROM place WHERE ID = databaseid; ]]
   db:exec( tablefill2 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The databaseid needs to be wrapped like thi.

```
UPDATE place SET xcor = testvalue[3] WHERE Id=']]..databaseid..[[';
```